# Trying to convert excel into db then: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "175": syntax error

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

Im using the following code to convert excel file into sqlite db file, but i have the error when I python the file.
the error is

```
$ python exceltosql.py
exceltosql.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).
  sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceltosql.py", line 38, in <module>
    con.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "175": syntax error
```

My python version is 3 and sqlite version is 3.22. Could anyone give me some help about it?
I really dont know what couse sqlite3.OperationalError: near "175": syntax error 
and i tried a lot of way, but I can not solve this problem.

```
'''
This code uses the openpyxl package for playing around with excel using Python code
to convert complete excel workbook (all sheets) to an SQLite database
The code assumes that the first row of every sheet is the column name
Every sheet is stored in a separate table
The sheet name is assigned as the table name for every sheet
'''

import sqlite3
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re

def slugify(text, lower=1):
    if lower == 1:
        text = text.strip().lower()
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w _-]+', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'[- ]+', '_', text)
    return text

#Replace with a database name
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
#replace with the complete path to youe excel workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename=r'C:\Users\38983\Desktop\Atria\into_db\telemetric.xlsx')

sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()

for sheet in sheets:
    ws = wb[sheet] 

    columns= []
    query = 'CREATE TABLE ' + str(slugify(sheet)) + '(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT'
    for row in next(ws.rows):
        query += ', ' + slugify(row.value) + ' TEXT'
        columns.append(slugify(row.value))
    query += ');'

    con.execute(query)

    tup = []
    for i, rows in enumerate(ws):
        tuprow = []
        if i == 0:
            continue
        for row in rows:
            tuprow.append(unicode(row.value).strip()) if unicode(row.value).strip() != 'None' else tuprow.append('')
        tup.append(tuple(tuprow))


    insQuery1 = 'INSERT INTO ' + str(slugify(sheet)) + '('
    insQuery2 = ''
    for col in columns:
        insQuery1 += col + ', '
        insQuery2 += '?, '
    insQuery1 = insQuery1[:-2] + ') VALUES('
    insQuery2 = insQuery2[:-2] + ')'
    insQuery = insQuery1 + insQuery2

    con.executemany(insQuery, tup)
    con.commit()

con.close()
```

Comment: I'd guess `slugify()` forgot some special character. Print out the value of `query`.

Comment: $ python exceltosql.py
exceltosql.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).
  sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()

Comment: CREATE TABLE -------a lot of row data-----Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceltosql.py", line 38, in <module>
    con.execute(query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "175": syntax error

Comment: Hi CL, I added print(query), it shows CREATE TABLE then followed all the row

Comment: it fails on `CREATE TABLE`. probably some sheet has numeric name.

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the actual output secret.

Comment: dear sKwa, you are right!

Comment: dear Cl, is because my table have numeric name